# Is it possible to loop through datasets in SSRS report and save each dataset as an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS and I just want to know if it is possible to loop through datasets in an SSRS report and save each dataset separately as an Excel spreadsheet.

For example, if we have a report with 5 managers, if you click on each one of these managers you can see/drill down to all the supervisors that are under this manager and if you click on any of those supervisors you can see all the employees that are under that particular supervisor. Now, what I'm trying to do is I want to save each one of the managers' (and supervisors' eventually) downline in an excel document (although it really can be in any format as long as they can later drill down on it) so that each manager can only get his/her own supervisors/employees. Can this be done in SSRS and if so I'll try to figure out how. Also, if you think there is a better way to restrict every manager from seeing every other manager's supervisors employees please let me know. The report that I currently have is perfect but everyone can see other people's supervisors/employees and their data.

Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, I forgot the main thing - if it can be done, can it be automated somehow?

Comment: Create a SSRS report with Manager parameter, which will diplay his or her supernisor and then export to the excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to generate flat files to send out, then you have to create a parameter on your report, deploy it to the report server, and then create 5 subscriptions to that report.

in each subscription you can set the parameter and where you want to write/email the file.

If the subscriptions part doesn't work well for you (if you have too many to manage), you can use data driven subscriptions (enterprise edition feature), rs.exe scripts (if you figure out how it works), or use my new cool tool (http://busysreports.codeplex.com)

also, you don't have to generate flat files, you can also set up some security so when the managers open the report in reporting services they see only their data.